# How to use ng model values as global in my application?

Tags: angular, html

I have two module, one is View Items Module and another one is add Items module.

I have `app.view.component.ts`, `app.add.component.cs` , But now how can I use `[(ng-model)]` values as global

This is `add.component.html`

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr height="25">
        <td align="right" width="45%">
            <div class="label-man">
                <span>* Item ID</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <!-- <td><input type="text" style="width:300px" id="itemIDVal"></td> -->
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width:300px" name="itemId" id="FstTex" [(ngModel)]=" itemId">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25">
        <td align="right">
            <div class="label-man">
                <span>Item Description</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width:300px" id="itemDescriptionVal" [(ngModel)]=" itemDesc">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25">
        <td align="right">
            <div class="label-man">
                <span>* Item Classification</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width:300px" id="classificationVal" [(ngModel)]=" Classification">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25">
        <td align="right">
            <div class="label-man">
                <span>* Item Sub-Classification</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width:300px" id="subClassificationVal" [(ngModel)]=" subClassification" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="buttons">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Save</span>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%; table-layout: fixed;" class="newtbl">
    <thead>
        <tr height="25">
            <th width="25%">Item ID</th>
            <th width="25%">Item Description</th>
            <th width="25%">Item classification</th>
            <th>Item Sub-Classification</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{inputItem.itemId}}</td>
            <td>{{inputItem.itemDesc}}</td>
            <td>{{inputItem.Classification}}</td>
            <td>{{inputItem.subClassification}}</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And This is `view.componet.html`

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Item ID" [(ngModel)]="itemId" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Item Description" [(ngModel)]="itemDesc" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder=" Please Enter Classification" [(ngModel)]="Classification" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Sub-Class" [(ngModel)]="subClassification" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="25">
            <th width="25%">Item ID</th>
            <th width="25%">Item Description</th>
            <th width="25%">Item Classification</th>
            <th>Item Sub-Classification
                <span class="buttons">
                    <a>
                        <span>Add Record</span>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{itemId}}</td>
            <td>{{itemDesc}}</td>
            <td>{{Classification}}</td>
            <td>{{subClassification}}</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The scenario is when I entered values in `add.component.html` those values directly append as a row in `view.component.html`. I am new to Angular.

Comment: erm.... can u share a screenshot on how the ui looks like as well? Also, both component are display in same page or a individual page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve what you want is through `Services`. Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fupv27?file=src/app/second.component.html)

For simplicity, I didn't use `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`.

I have two components, let's called them `InputComponent` and `TableComponent`.

First one holds the inputs and second one displays the data.

I, also, created a service called `DataService`.

It holds an array called `data` and a method to push new rows to the `data`

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  data: any[] = [];

  push(row) {
    this.data.push(row);
  }

}
```

Let's take a look at `InputComponent`
As you can see, I injected `DataComponent` and created two inputs with `ngModel`s

When user clicks on `button`, I push this data into `dataService.data` array and clear the input.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input-comp',
  template: `
    <div>Enter first column: <input [(ngModel)]="model.firstValue" /></div>
    <div>Enter second column: <input [(ngModel)]="model.secondValue" /></div>
    <button (click)="onBtnClick()">Click me</button>
  `
})
export class InputComponent  {
  model = {};

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  onBtnClick() {
    this.dataService.push(this.model);
    this.model = {};
  }
}
```

On `TableComponent` I display `dataService.data` to the user as follows

`table.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-comp',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html'
})
export class TableComponent  {

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {}
}
```

`table.component.html`

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of dataService.data">
      <td>{{row.firstValue}}</td>
      <td>{{row.secondValue}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**The solution above DOES NOT work when `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is present**

The stackblitz above works just fine because I did not change `changeDetection` of `TableComponent`. However, if you set `changeDetection` of `TableComponent` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, you'll see it won't work. [Check it out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjpxpf?file=src/app/table.component.ts)

It is because, now you tell `Angular` to listen only to events such as any changes in `Input`s (which we don't have any), internal events etc. If you don't know about `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` you should read about it. It provides a great performance improvement.

Anyway, let's refactor our `service` and `component`s to support `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

[Our final code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itbkmk?file=src/app/table.component.html)

First I refactored `DataService` to have a `BehaviourSubject`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private data: any[] = [];

  private dataSubject: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject(this.data);
  public readonly data$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable();
  push(row) {
    this.data.push(row);
    this.dataSubject.next(this.data);
  }
}
```

Now, instead of exposing `data` array to the outside world, we expose an Observable called `data$`. And, when a new item comes through, we update our inner `data` and publish it through `dataSubject.next`. This way, an event is fired and all the subscribers are notified.

Let's take a look at our `TableComponent`

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of dataService.data$ | async">
      <td>{{row.firstValue}}</td>
      <td>{{row.secondValue}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The only difference is instead of accessing `data` array directly, we access `dataService.data$` Observable and subscribe to it by `async` pipe. Now, everyone is happy and everything works just fine.

**Without RxJs**

There is a way without RxJs but I think it will be cumbersome if there are many levels of components. Take a look at [final code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvaqs8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I deleted `data.service` which was responsible for data passing between two components. Instead, now `InputComponent` emits an event when a new input is entered and the button is clicked.

`TableComponent` retrieves `data` through an `@Input`.

`InputComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input-comp',
  template: `

  <div>Enter first column: <input [(ngModel)]="model.firstValue" /></div>
  <div>Enter second column: <input [(ngModel)]="model.secondValue" /></div>
  <button (click)="onBtnClick()">Click me</button>
  `
})
export class InputComponent  {
  model = {};

  @Output() modelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  onBtnClick() {
    this.modelChange.emit(this.model);
    this.model = {};
  }
}
```

`TableComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-comp',
  template:`
    <table border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
          <td>{{row.firstValue}}</td>
          <td>{{row.secondValue}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TableComponent  {

  @Input() data: any[];

}
```

`AppComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input-comp (modelChange)="onModelChange($event)"></input-comp>
    <table-comp [data]="data"></table-comp>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  data = [];

  onModelChange(newModel) {
    this.data = [...this.data, newModel];
  }
}
```

As you may have noticed, I don't do `this.data.push(newModel)`. It is because, when you push a new data to an existing array, its object reference won't change. Therefore, angular change detection will not trigger for `TableComponent` and update the table.

`this.data = [...this.data, newModel]` takes existing `data` array and spread it out with `...` and add the `newModel`. This way, you always create a new instance and change detection will work just fine.

Comment: HI Bunyamin is there anty other way, is it possible to do without RXJS?, Give me an Idea.

Comment: @SamudralaRamu I edited my answer and suggested another solution.